# PowerPoint: How to manipulate narration timings for on-click animations (not just advance to next slide)?

Tags: audio, vba, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using Office 365, version 2206 of PowerPoint, but this question applies to several versions. When you record narrations in PowerPoint, this feature allows you to set timings for advancing animations and advancing to the next slide. PowerPoint handles the advance to the next slide by filling the "After" field on the Transitions tab. However, it isn't clear how PowerPoint handles the advancing of animations or where it saves the timings for advancing animations in time with the narration. This is clearly different from the normal animation timings, because it applies also to animations that are set to "Start On Click," which do not otherwise have a timing set.

For example, if you have several animations set to "Start On Click", then you record narration with click timings, then the animations will run automatically during a slideshow when you reach the appropriate point in the narration as though you had clicked the mouse. However, when you look at the properties of the animations, they are still set to "Start On Click." Looking through the VBA objects, I can't figure out where the timings are stored. In particular, they don't appear to be under ActivePresentation.Slides(x).TimeLine. Anyone have any idea where the animation timings are stored or how PowerPoint implements them?

You're probably wondering why it matters. Well, if you insert audio directly without using the narration feature and try instead to split the audio into separate sound clips that play at the appropriate point in the animation sequence, it works terribly. If the user accidentally clicks, PowerPoint will try to play multiple audio clips at the same time, causing a horrid cacophony of narration. However, using the narration feature can be annoyingly inflexible. For example, if you want to modify the sound file with an external program after recording it, this can mess with the synchronization of timings. Sometimes would be nice to be able to modify the timings directly instead of having to re-record them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely understanding the issue here, but if you want to synchronize animations with specific points in the narration, it might be far simpler (and probably more accurate/reliable) to set bookmarks in the narration, then set the other animation events (timing properties) to trigger off the appropriate bookmark.

Comment: Thanks; you're right, I should give that a try next time.

Comment: There's a bug in the timings "feature" of PowerPoint going back to 2010 whereby the timings are completely ignored when recording. Another bug, under certain conditions, will make PP ignore your click AND the timings, but happens if you apply to all slides (which also corrupts animations). If you make too many changes, powerpoint will corrupt your presentation. MS has never fixed these bugs (also in 365), so probably best to use another piece of software.